# C# URL, Get all files of type "audio/webm"

Tags: c#, download, youtube, webclient

I'm making an app that enables me to download YouTube videos. If you weren't aware by selecting the network tab on a YouTube video then refreshing the page, filtering using "mime-type:audio/webm" {EDIT:: and removing &range=.. from the url} you get access to all the video's files like just audio, just video, low quality, high quality etc.

The app I'm wanting to make but can't seem to figure out will go to https://youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID, filter the requests by "mime-type:audio/webm" and list all of the links found.

How could I access this from C#?

[a screenshot of what I'm talking about in regards to video types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thkmp.jpg)

[image: a screenshot of what I'm talking about in regards to video types]

Comment: HI, did this help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can clearly see that the web request is initiated by a javascript.

By doing so, it has been made hard to initiate such a request from C#, because;

- you either need to parse and execute the javascript, or
- recreate the generated URL's in C#, or
- use a proxy to capture the incoming data

Another option would be to check out [Google's API](https://console.developers.google.com/projectselector2/apis/dashboard?supportedpurview=project), but I am not sure they expose such functionality.